# Is it possible to drag and drop GridView rows with jQuery sortable?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, jquery-ui-sortable

I have tried to implement this in the following way:

GridView:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridViewUnavailableDestination" runat="server" Visible="False" 
      Width="98%" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" 
      GridLines="None" CssClass="sortable">
      <Columns>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label ID="idUnavailable" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("idUnavailable") %>' Visible="false"></asp:Label>
                  <asp:Label Visible="true" runat="server" ID="unavailableLabel" Text='<%# bind("name")  %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label Visible="true" runat="server" ID="unavailableTypeLabel" Text='<%# bind("type")  %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="RT">
              <ItemTemplate>
                  <asp:Label Visible="true" runat="server" ID="unavailableRTLabel" Text='<%# bind("ringingTime")  %>'></asp:Label>
              </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
      </Columns>
  </asp:GridView>
```

And this is my javascript in the MasterPage:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(function () {
            $(".sortable tbody").sortable();
            $(".sortable tbody").disableSelection();
        });
});
```

However, it does not work.

Any ideas on how to make this work? Or if it is possible at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, it is required to have a look at the following post:

http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

It is about a recent jQuery plugin that allows to Drag and Drop table elements. This is useful for GridViews since the browser renders it as a table. However, this might not be enough to get the solution to the problem, as it has been clearly described by this post, which works with GridViews specifically:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1684346.aspx/1?tableDnD+onDragClass+not+working+on+asp+net+GRIDVIEW

Hope this helps people with the same issue!

Answer (score 2):

you should below links....

http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/

http://www.pedrera.com/blog/asp-net-listview-drag-and-drop-reordering-using-jquery/

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/DragAndDropGridView.aspx

http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/make-table-rows-sortable-using-jquery-ui-sortable/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It led me find an answer to this issue. I will post it soon. Cheers